# JavaScript - How to make sure array manipulations are persistent inside a function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference, ecmascript-5

I am trying to write a JavaScript function (ES5) that will take in an array, filter it, and set the original array to the new one.

Here is my plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/OWeOjJ3SLVGYRaweyy3Z

Here is the basic pseudocode of what I am trying to do:

```
var result = [{ 'date': '20171116' }, { 'date': '20171115' }];
var data = { 'date': '2017116' };
deleteEntry(data, result);
console.log(result); //should  have one entry

function deleteEntry(data, result) {
  result = result.filter(function(item) {
    return item.date !== data.date;
  });
}
```

I believe the issue is to do with array references. I am not sure how to accomplish the task.

Comment: Just remove `, result` from the parameters...

Comment: "`data`" and "`result`" are two very confusing parameter names.

Comment: I am not sure why I got a downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.filter returns a new array instance so you loose the reference of your original array when you do *result = result.filter(...)*. You can use array.splice instead:

```js
var result = [{ 'date': '20171116' }, { 'date': '20171115' }];
var data = { 'date': '20171116' };
deleteEntry(data, result);
function deleteEntry(data, result) {
    var index = result.findIndex(item => item.date === data.date);
    result.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should return the modified array and assign it's response to the `result` variable:

```
function deleteEntry(data, result) {
  return result.filter(function(item) {
    return item.date !== data.date;
  });
}

result = deleteEntry(data, result);
```

Comment: it did not produce the expected result

Comment: @user It should work fine. Give us a version of your plunk that demonstrates this.

Comment: @hsz answer is correct, set the `result = deleteEntry(data, result)`
you did not set it back to the result variable

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) where you delete all elements and add the new elements of filtering.

```js
function deleteEntry(data, result) {
    Array.prototype.splice.apply(result, [0, result.length].concat(result.filter(function(item) {
        return item.date !== data.date;
    })));
}

var result = [{ date: '20171116' }, { date: '20171115' }],
    data = { date: '20171116' };
    
deleteEntry(data, result);
console.log(result);
```

ES6

```js
function deleteEntry(data, result) {
    var temp = result.filter(item => item.date !== data.date);
    result.length = 0;
    result.push(...temp);
}

var result = [{ date: '20171116' }, { date: '20171115' }],
    data = { date: '20171116' };
    
deleteEntry(data, result);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: So complicated for such a simple aim

Comment: but it keeps the object reference.